# How do I design an href to use as an anchor.attr in js but not open a window when clicked?

Tags: php, javascript, html, href

I have an href function in my php file.  I use it as anchor.attr('href') in my js file to show a large version of an image when someone rolls over a thumbnail of the image.  That works fine.  The problem is that if someone clicks on the large version now being displayed, it replaces my php file with a file containing the large image.  I want it to do nothing.

I have tried using something else in the js for the anchor.attr like name and title but it is executing an img statement and requires the href to function.

If i put href'#", the anchor.attr errors off because there is no file there to execute against.

Is there a way to allow the usage of the href for the js function but not open a new window with the image in it when clicked.

Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the JavaScript code that displays the large version of the images?

Comment: some relevant code? (increase your acc rate)

Comment: You have 14 questions and none of them has an accepted answer, this is of course possible, although highly improbable. So, take a look at your previous questions and when an answer helped you solve the questions, mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("a").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  // do something
});
```

or you can use the javascript `return false` to stop anchor tag from redirecting

```
$('a').click(function () {
      return false;
};
```